# How to get notified when a user is locked?

Tags: rules

After 5 unsuccessful logins, a user gets locked. How can I get notified? I tried with the Rules module without success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Login Security module](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_security) for D7. It has notifications.

Form the project page :

> A set of notifications by email or Nagios may help the site
>   administrator to know when something is happening with the login form
>   of their site: